# How to dispose of Chinese Privet prunings?

Tags: weeds, privet

Chinese Privet is considered a weed in New Zealand (and it definitely behaves like one on my lifestyle block)

I've removed a hole lot of privet growing in my hedge, but I don't know how to dispose of the cuttings.  If I absolutely have to I can throw then in the general waste as a last resort, but are there better options?

The privet just has leaves - no flowers or fruit.

Am I correct in surmising that Chinese privet spreads by birds eating the seeds and dropping them?   If so, am i safe to put the cuttings in an area at the back of my property or give it a few days/weeks and then put it through my garden shredder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this site from Tennessee](https://www.nashvilletreeconservationcorps.org/treenews/chinese-privet-the-history-of-this-invasive-plant-and-the-problems-it-creates), US, where the Chinese Privet is also considered an invasive weed, Chinese Privet spreads from place to place by seeds eaten by birds, and by root. If you've cut down your privet without removing the roots or treating the stump with an herbicide like Triclopyr, the roots will resprout.

This plant is similar to buckthorn and Asian honeysuckle in my area. When we remove these shrubs without seeds on them, we simply chip them and use them as mulch, or burn them and rejoice in their deaths. We burn any branches with seeds.